# A* (A star) search algorithm implementation still not working

Tags: python, a-star

I haven't gotten a response on my other post since I updated it and I really need some help, so I'm reposting. The code below is the important bit, but a link to the full code is here: https://github.com/amstrudy/nao-ncsu/blob/master/oop_a_star.py

I've been following along the [Wikipedia pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm#Pseudocode) for an A * implementation in Python. My code reaches the goal, but I can't seem to figure out how to reconstruct the actual path. It doesn't work because the piece of code where cameFrom is updated is only updated once at the end when the goal is reached. I don't understand that really but it's how the wikipedia article had the pseudocode.

```
def a_star ():

    # create node object for home
    home_node = Node(home, goal, home)

    # set of nodes already evaluated
    closedSet = []

    # set of currently discovered nodes that are not evaluated yet
    # initially, only the start node is known
    openSet = [home_node]

    while len(openSet) != 0:

        minIndex = 0;
        for i in list(range(len(openSet))):
            if openSet[i] < openSet[minIndex]:
                minIndex = i
        cur_node = openSet[minIndex] # expand on node with smallest fScore

        cur_node.generateNeighbors() # make new nodes to check

        if cur_node.location == home_node.goal:
            print("Made it to the goal!")
            return reconstruct(cur_node)

        openSet.pop(minIndex)
        closedSet.append(cur_node)

        for neighbor in cur_node.neighbors:

            if neighbor in closedSet:
                continue

            if neighbor not in openSet:
                openSet.append(neighbor)

            if neighbor.gScore >= cur_node.gScore:
                print(neighbor.gScore)
                print(cur_node.gScore)
                continue # this is not eh better path

            # this path is the best for now, so record it
            neighbor.cameFrom = cur_node

        print(cur_node)
        printMap(cur_node.location)

def reconstruct(target):
    path = []
    while target:
        print("here")
        path.append(target.location)
        target = target.cameFrom
    return path
```

For those commenting that this is a duplicate: yeah it is. I'm not getting a response on the old post, so I edited it and reposted. I will delete the old post.

Comment: can you update full code
with imports and all @amstrudy

Comment: Here's a link to the full code on github. https://github.com/amstrudy/nao-ncsu/blob/master/oop_a_star.py

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trouble with A Star Reconstruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47210981/trouble-with-a-star-reconstruction)

Comment: @Shadow He mentioned it above

Comment: @amstrudy what are arguments to pass to run it ?

Comment: You pass in the start node and end node. So for example (0, 0) and (2, 2). You have to put it in quotes so the terminal accepts it though. @Tilak Putta

Comment: There are a bunch of issues with the code at your link. Your `Node.gScore` function (which gets masked by its own return value after it's called by `__init__`, which seems like a bad idea) computes the same value for every node, so the lines in the `astar` function that reject (for the purposes of updating `cameFrom` only) nodes that move farther away from the goal always reject everything. That check is wrong anyway, as the optimal path may need to move away from the goal before moving towards it.

Comment: @BIckknght Can you please elaborate what you mean by "masked by its own return value"? What are your suggestions for fixing the code?

Comment: Can u give me push access to your repository @amstrudy

Comment: @amstrudy I fixed it and i will push it into new branch and create a pull request